# RadControl DateTimePicker Selecting new time doesn't remove highlight from previous selection

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, datetimepicker, sitefinity

This is not browser specific - the behavior exists in Firefox and IE. The RadControl is being used within a User Control in a SiteFinity site.

Very little customization has been done to the control.

```
<telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="RadDateTimePicker1" runat="server"
     MinDate="2010/1/1" Width="250px">
      <ClientEvents></ClientEvents>
      <TimeView starttime="08:00:00" endtime="20:00:00"
           interval="02:00:00"></TimeView>
      <DateInput runat="server" ID="DateInput"></DateInput>
</telerik:RadDateTimePicker>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RadDateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer, I work for Telerik]

I don't specifically know what the issue is, however here are some general troubleshooting steps that might help unearth the issue:

1. Check for Javacript errors - (Firefox's Error Console would do it)
2. Isolate the RadDateTimePicker control from Sitefinity - (Create a normal ASPX page and place the RadDateTimePicker control on this page.  Does it work in this environment?)
3. Check for stylesheet issues using Firebug and/or remove stylesheets (backup first).

In general, keep simplifying until it starts working then re-add complexity until it breaks again.  This normally tells me where the problem is.

Alternately, you could send your project/code to [Telerik support](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet.aspx).  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing MinDate to use:

```
RadDateTimePicker1.MinDate = System.DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", System.DateTime.Now.Month, System.DateTime.Now.Day, System.DateTime.Now.Year - 1))
```

And tell me if the behavior changes.

Also, is the new highlight being shown as well, or is it stuck on the old highlighting completely?

Comment: This didn't change the behavior.

The new highlighting does show in addition to the old. If you keep clicking the different times, it adds them to the selection, though it's only visibly, since the textbox showing the date/time only shows the most recently selected time.